# Code not writing to SD in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, email, bitmap

I am trying to write an app that will give me a screenshot and email this to me (not the client)
I am stuck on the first part. 
Why is the code not capturing the png image into the SD Card?
Can someone please help.
After that where do i place the code to send the email to myself?
I have added this to my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is my .java file:

```
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                final RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);

                layout.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bitmap bm=takeScreenShot(layout);

                        try{
                            if(bm !=null){
                                savedScreenShot(bm);
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
    //TAKE SCREENSHOT
    private Bitmap takeScreenShot(View v)
    {
        Bitmap screenShot=null;
        try
        {
            //GET WIDTH AND HEIGHT
            int width=v.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height=v.getMeasuredHeight();

            screenShot=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            //DRAW CANVAS
            Canvas c=new Canvas(screenShot);
            v.draw(c);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return screenShot;
    }

    //SAVE TO EXTERNAL STORAGE
    private void savedScreenShot(Bitmap bm){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao =null;
        File file=null;

        try{
            //COMPRESS AND WRITE OUTPUT STREAM
            bao=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,40,bao);

            //WRITE AS A FILE TO SD CARD
            file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Pictures/order.png");
            file.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bao.toByteArray());
            fos.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Logcat

```
    01-20 11:52:50.399 30175-30201/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 11:52:50.399 30175-30201/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad75f220, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-20 11:52:58.544 30175-30181/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.093ms
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot.MainActivity.savedScreenShot(MainActivity.java:86)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:19)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:42)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-20 11:52:58.713 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-20 11:52:58.715 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-20 11:52:58.716 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-20 11:52:58.716 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-20 11:52:58.716 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-20 11:52:58.716 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
01-20 11:52:58.716 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
01-20 11:52:58.716 30175-30175/com.example.publi.almatakescreenshot W/System.err:   ... 10 more
```

Comment: Well first tell if there are any catches. Tell exactly how your code flowd.

Comment: Updated question please revert to above.

Comment: It is ok that you posted the logcat as it clearly mentions the problem and even a line number. Please comment first.

Comment: Ok Can you please help How to fix.

Comment: Are you sure that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Pictures/"` actually exists before trying to write to it. And if Pictures does exist, are you sure this is how you get the correct folder path? Take a look here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html